# Arduino Zero Wifi

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

**Has anyone gotten WiFi to work on the Zero?** When I so much as include any Wifi header files my code compiles but stops executing all together. I have tried using the Library Manager and it auto included the following:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFiServer.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
```

Wifi.h depends on SPI.h so I have included that as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to include *any* WiFi library. [WiFiClient](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiClient), [WiFiServer](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiServer) and [WiFiUdp](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiUDPConstructor) are internal classes.

If you own an original or compatible WiFi shield, its best to start with the Guides provided at [www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoWiFiShield](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoWiFiShield) - there is only `SPI.h` and `WiFi.h` used.

More details about the WiFi libary are listed at the [WiFi References](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFi).

If the examples does not work (maybe its a zero specific problem) there is also an [arduino forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/), where you could ask for help.

But personally I only own a normal ethernet shield, so i can't provide a self-tested WiFi example.

Comment: Using WiFi.h was a known issue to break all sketches with the Arduino Zero. However this bug has since been fixed. Thanks for trying to contribute.